# How can I generate document from Android Source zip file?

Tags: java, android, javadoc, documentation-generation

I downloaded Android's 4.4 source file and I would like to get its API as html?

I have ADT bundle and IntellijIdea 13 installed, I tried to import and then generate Doc, but I couldn't,some errors, I searched over internet but I could not find a good answers, is possible to generate API document without downloading?

Note: I want to generate the docs, I don't want to download the doc from somewhere else.

Comment: what are the errors? You can download the docs offline and then put them in right folders

Comment: Actually Google blocked Iran and I am not able to get it also my proxy is slow! is there any way?

Comment: why not remote upload the docs to a website and then download it from there?

Comment: I don't understand, why should i upload, when I have source?

Comment: do you have the source to download the docs?

Comment: I have Source code of Android, and it source like java source has documentation, I want to get its documentation like for example javafx api documentation as HTML.

Comment: if i am not wrong then what you mean is that you want javadocs?

Comment: Yes I want javadocs of Android source zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that the answers was not my solution.

in javadoc documentation there is option for documenting multiple packages,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html

I first extracted android source.zip file and then I used **javadoc** command in command-prompt. like so:

```
javadoc -J-Xmx1024m -d [DESTINATION] -sourcpath [SOURCE OF PACKAGES] -subpackages [PACKAGES]
```

-J-Xmx1024m is allocation of memory to VM and for multiple packages under src/ folder should be used like this,

-subpackages android:androidx:java and so

Answer (score 1):

here's the link to direct download link for downloading doc [download javadocs for all versions](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.google.android%22%20AND%20a%3a%22android%22). If you can't still download it directly then please mention in comments i will provide you alternate download link.

Comment: Thank you @Rohan for time, but I found the solution, after some search the answer was in javadoc documentation itself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Android SDK? If you do, the documentation is in the subfolder `docs`. Look at `docs/reference/packages.html` for javadocs.